# sql calculating query doesn't run, #1054 unknown column in field list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create query that would show is the certain section is passed by certain account_id. It means all lessons of the section is checked = 1(true). I tried this solution:

```
SELECT count(*) as checked,(
  SELECT count(*)  
  FROM lessons 
  WHERE section_id = 1 
  GROUP BY section_id
) as cnt, (checked = cnt) as passed
FROM lessons l 
LEFT JOIN progress p ON l.id = p.lesson_id
WHERE l.section_id = 1 AND p.account_id = 3 AND checked = 1 
GROUP BY l.section_id
```

But it returns error:

> #1054 unknown 'cnt' column in field list.

What do I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: `cnt` doesn't exist on that side of the statement since it's an alias. You'll have to add the select to the equation as well, or rethink your query.

Comment: You can only use aliases established in a SELECT expression in the post-WHERE clauses (ORDER BY, GROUP BY, HAVING)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should move all conditions on the `p.*` columns to the ON clause. Otherwise you will convert the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN and `COUNT(*)` will always be the same as in your subquery. However you don't even need that subquery - You can get the same value with `COUNT(p.lesson_id)` instead. It will ignore all rows with `NULL`.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as cnt,
    COUNT(p.lesson_id) as checked,
    COUNT(*) = COUNT(p.lesson_id) as passed
FROM lessons l
LEFT JOIN progress p
  ON  p.lesson_id  = l.id
  AND p.account_id = 3
  AND p.checked    = 1
WHERE l.section_id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The unknown 'cnt' is generated from  (checked=cnt) as passed.  Try this

```
SELECT checked, cnt, (checked=cnt) as passed FROM (SELECT count(*) as checked,(
  SELECT count(*)  
  FROM lessons 
  WHERE section_id = 1 
  GROUP BY section_id
) as cnt
FROM lessons l 
LEFT JOIN progress p ON l.id = p.lesson_id
WHERE l.section_id = 1 AND p.account_id = 3 AND checked = 1 
GROUP BY l.section_id) tblA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as checked, (SELECT count(*)  FROM lessons 
WHERE section_id = 1 GROUP BY section_id) as cnt, 
((SELECT count(*)  FROM lessons WHERE section_id = 1 GROUP BY section_id) = checked) pass
FROM lessons l LEFT JOIN progress p ON l.id = p.lesson_id
WHERE l.section_id = 1 AND p.account_id = 3 AND checked = 1 GROUP BY l.section_id
```

Thanks to @aynber. Though I'm not sure if this solution isn't too bulky.